# og:image take php variable

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

I have a image tag that gets a php variable from another page,

```
 <img src="<?php echo urldecode($_GET['pic']); ?>" width="100%" alt="" />.
```

It works fine. I would like to know how to take that and make it work with the meta tags og:image and itemprop="image". I've tried several ways, but had no luck.

Thanks,
Darrell

Comment: what the the `several ways` that did not work? share code

Comment: why can't you do this ?

<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo urldecode($_GET['pic']); ?>"/>

Comment: userD Tried that exactly, did'nt work. It takes another image off of the page and uses it instead.

Comment: how can it just take another image ? can you please explain and what kind of values does $_GET['pic'] contain anyways ?

Comment: userD The pic variable is url path to the image. I get an unable to parse error on the facebook debugger.

Comment: i hope you are passing pic parameters while using the debug tool

Comment: userD I made sure I was passing them, and still get the error og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'. My og:url is working and has the page the image is on in the url, and passes the same variable, it displays the page with the image on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9823/discussion-between-userd-and-darrell)

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be in the HTML head.

Here is a modified example from http://ogp.me/

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo urldecode($_GET['pic']); ?>" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Comment: Nick C. We have it in the head, just as you posted.

Comment: Make sure the image path is an absolute URL.